# Purpose of the Before Statement and After Statement Sections of a Compound Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

From what I understand, the Before Statement section of a compound trigger is used to initialize placeholders that don't need to use :NEW or :OLD to be initialized. An example can be seen here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER zipcode_compound
    FOR INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON zipcode
    COMPOUND TRIGGER
    v_date   DATE;
    v_user   VARCHAR2 (30);

    BEFORE STATEMENT
    IS
    BEGIN
        v_date := SYSDATE;
        v_user := USER;
    END BEFORE STATEMENT;
END zipcode_compound;
```

Also from what I understand, the After Statement section of a compound trigger is used to handle mutating table errors.

In addition, I believe that we can add whatever else we want to occur before and after all of the rows are evaluated to the appropriate sections.

Is my understanding correct? If not, please specify what I am not comprehending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before creating a `compound trigger`, you should think about what you want to do. Every `compound trigger` can be split to multiple `triggers`. If you have got multiple `triggers` on a `table`, that's the point to think about a `compound trigger`, to merge those functionalities into one `trigger`.

Here's the default template Toad creates for `Compound triggers` - it's explained pretty good:

```
COMPOUND TRIGGER
    tmpVar NUMBER;
  BEFORE STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    begin
      -- we cannot reference :new or :old in the before statement section
      tmpVar := 0;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
      RAISE;
    END;
  END BEFORE STATEMENT;

  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    begin
      -- we can read or write to :new or :old in the before each row section
      tmpVar := 0;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
      RAISE;
    END;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;

  AFTER EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    begin
      tmpVar := 0;
      -- we can read, but not write to :new or :old in the after each row section
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
      RAISE;
    END;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    begin
      -- we cannot reference :new or :old in the after statement section
      tmpVar := 0;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
      RAISE;
    END;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END MyTrigger;
```

Comment: Danke für die erklärung!